# LeadConvert with Dedupe

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I'm looking at existing code to convert a lead in a lead trigger. I didn't write this.

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();

lc.setBypassAccountDedupeCheck(true);
lc.setBypassContactDedupecheck(true);
```

I don't see these methods in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm). From their names it looks like if set true you skip doing the dedupe check for either the account or contact. Is the official documentation missing these methods?

Comment: I've asked the docs team for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Salesforce Docs team](https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs/status/1356326269282119681), these methods were meant to be marked as "internal use only" (we'd call those *private methods*). Do not attempt to use them, and do not rely on their behavior to work properly.